# How to create *.idx subtitle files

Tags: windows, video, subtitles

I am trying to play movies from a USB drive on my DVD player.

I have subtitles for different languages for a movie. (filename.en.srt, filename.fr.srt etc) When I place all the *.srt files in the same directory as the movie file, the DVD player recognises only the first one.

However, if there is only one *.sub file which contains all the language subtitles, and an indexer *.idx file, then the DVD player is able to recognise all the language subtitles.

Can I create an *.idx file manually? 
Or
Is there any software which allows me to create an idx file that indexes multiple *.srt files or combines them?

Answer (score 1):

**[Subtitle Workshop](http://www.urusoft.net/products.php?cat=sw)** can convert convert .srt subtitles to .idx/.sub

*Subtitle Workshop is freeware.*

Answer (score 0):

Subtitle Workshop (closed source/dead) can neither read nor write sub/idx files.

[BDSup2Sub](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=145277) (open source) can be used to create sub/idx files from srt files.
Another option is SubtitleCreator.